# Spring Web client timeout fallback

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, webclient

I am having trouble with timeout fallback with spring web client. I want to call another method while timeout error happens. My web client call method:

```
String response = bkashWebClient
    .webClient()
    .get()
    .uri(queryPaymentUri, paymentId)
    .header("Authorization", bkashToken)
    .header("X-APP-Key", appKey)
    .retrieve()
    .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, clientResponse ->
        Mono.error(new Exception("Error occurred while calling grant token" + clientResponse.statusCode())))
    .bodyToMono(String.class)
    .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
    .block();
```

I want to call a method suppose `abc()` while a timeout event happens. But I am not able to figure it out. How should I handle such a way so that when a timeout happens it will call another method and the method's return type is not Mono?

Comment: writing a costume exception class wouldn't help?

Comment: @Lrrr No..I need to call another method. And it will fetch another response from third party server.

Comment: You can use `.onErrorResume` to capture the error and handle it. As for  "return type is not Mono" - `WebClient` is a reactive client and most of API are async (return `Mono`). In case you want to call some side-effect operation like logging or record metric you could use `.doOnError` that is sync.
In addition, not sure why but you are blocking request. In case this is intended - you could simply use `try-catch` to capture exception because after `block` everything is synchronous.

Comment: Thanks @Alex. Yes currently I am using .doOnError . And yes the blocking is intentional.

Comment: you can do something like `Mono.fromCallable(() -> blockingCall())` inside onErrorResume